# ListView with a search filter

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this piece of code I've been working on for quite some time. It's a ListView with a search filter. Inside each row, it contains a user Image, a User's name and how many friends they have in common. Also the row contains a button each, for actions.

I'm just indeed of some code refactoring, maybe some guidance? Different collections that I could use to tone the heavy code down.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    res = getResources();
    searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    list = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    friendList2 = new ArrayList<Friend>();

    nameBlock = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
    descBlock = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nameBlock.length; i++) {
        names.add((String)nameBlock[i]);
    }
    descr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < descBlock.length; i++) {
        descr.add((String)descBlock[i]);
    }
    images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < imageBlock.length; i++) {
        images.add((Integer)imageBlock[i]);
    }
    //imageBlock = res.getIntArray(R.array.images);

    int size = nameBlock.length;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        Log.d("FREINDADD", "Freind Added" + i);
        list.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i), false));
        friendList2.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i), false));
        //friendList2.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i)));
    }
    Log.i("Application", "Application started succesfully...");

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);


    setListAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i("VIRTU", "Count" + adapter.getCount());
    //adapter.getCount();


    searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            list.clear();
            textlength = searchField.getText().length();

            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
            {
                if (textlength <= names.get(i).length())
                {
                    if(names.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        Log.i("VirtuFriendList", "List recyling in process... ");
                        list.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i), false));

                    }
                  }
            }
            AppendList(list);

            }
    });


}
public void AppendList(ArrayList<Friend> list) {
    setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
} 

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public int pos;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView userName;
        TextView userDesc;
        ImageView userImage;
        Button userButton;
        int position;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            userImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            userName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            userDesc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mutualTitle);
            userButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        }
    }
    ViewHolder holder;
    View row;
    ViewGroup parent;
    int position;
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            row = convertView;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.pos = position;
            if(row == null) 
            {
                // If it is visible to the user, deploy the row(s) - allocated in local memory
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);

                Log.d("VIRTU", "Row deployed...");
            }
            else 
            {
                // Recycle the row if it is not visible to to the user - store in local memory
                holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
                Log.d("VIRTU", "Row recycled...");
            }
            final Friend temp = list.get(position);

            // Set the resources for each component in the list
            holder.userImage.setImageResource(temp.getImage());
            holder.userName.setText(temp.getName());
            holder.userDesc.setText(temp.getDesc());
            holder.userButton.setTag(position);

            holder.userButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String text = (String)searchField.getText().toString();

                    searchField.setText("");
                    Integer index = (Integer)v.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(context, index.intValue() + "..." + temp.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        destroy(list, names, descr, images, temp.getId());      
                    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        destroy(list, names, descr, images, index.intValue());
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(context);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                    searchField.setText(text);
                    searchField.setSelection(searchField.getText().length());
                }
            });


        return row;
    }
    public void destroy(ArrayList<Friend> list, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> desc, ArrayList<Integer> images, int position)  {
        list.remove(position);
        names.remove(position);
        desc.remove(position);
        images.remove(position);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few quick thoughts rather than a full review:

- Your `onCreate` is too long. Way too long!
- What is `lv`? Abbreviations are usually a bad idea. IDEs will do the typing for you, so meaningful names are a must.
- What is `friendList2`? Is there a `friendList1`? Why are there two? Why are they named like this? Names should represent the semantics, not count similar variables.
- Commented-out code is dead code and dead code rots. Remove it and use something like git instead. The one fear you cannot have is the fear of deleting code.
- Consistently misspelled: "freind" instead of "friend".
- `Log.d("FREINDADD", "Freind Added" + i);` – think about how log messages will look later on. Make them meaningful. This message is just slightly better than useless.
- `Log.i("Application", "Application started succesfully...");` – if it started successfully, then why do we wait for anything? An ellipsis (`…`) makes me think a process has started and is waiting now. Why is this log statement in the middle of the code?
- It is a Java standard to use camelCase, which means a method is named `appendList`, not `AppendList`.
- Use interfaces such as `List<T>` rather than implementations like `ArrayList<T>` for types of fields or parameters.
- Why does `AppendList` have a parameter, but never uses it?
- `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` should be one of the first things to remove. Don't leave dead and useless comments.